# Is there way to disable realtime update with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket, real-time-updates

I'm using Firebase in my frontend project.
More specific I use methods set() and once("value") to change and get data from realtime database table.
Now I see in the network tab of browser Firebase uses websocket connection to the server.
But I don't need any realtime updates.
Is there way to disable it?

Comment: I answered your question below. But it seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), given that you're already not receiving realtime updates when you use `once()`. **Why** do you not want to use web sockets?

Answer (score 1):

If you only use `once()` listeners, you already won't receive realtime updates. But Firebase will still use web sockets to communicate between client and server.

If for some reason you don't want to use web sockets, the only way to do so is to call the REST API of Firebase yourself. But you'll lose all benefits of using the SDK, such as its ability to handle loss of connectivity, it retrying of transactions, and more.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I'm doing. I use once() and I don't want to get any updates. There i no reason to use websockets unless I want realtime updates. I'm sorry to hear there is no flag to disable it. Using REST API is to complex to deal with it.

Comment: As I said in my comment on your question, this seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve by not using web sockets?